# Error while Loading image from form into MongoDB using Node/Expressjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, multipartform-data

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "size" argument must be of type number. Received type string ('/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEBLAEs...)
While Executing..

```
app.post('/register',upload.single('img'), (req, res) => {
    var img = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
    var encode_img = img.toString('base64');
    var final_dp={
        contentType:req.file.mimetype,
        dp:Buffer.alloc(encode_img,'base64')
    }
    try {
    const password = req.body.fPass; 
    const Spassword = req.body.sPass;// So that form's passwords are same
    if(password == Spassword){
        var obj = {
            dp: final_dp,
```

Followed retrieving image procedure from: `https://codebun.com/upload-image-in-database-using-nodejs-and-mongodb/`

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Buffer.alloc()` creates a new buffer object of the specified **size**, and you are sending the **string**. Use `Buffer.from()` instead.

```js
app.post('/register',upload.single('img'), (req, res) => {
    var img = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
    var base64_img = Buffer.from(img).toString('base64');
    var final_dp={
        contentType: req.file.mimetype,
        dp: base64_img 
    }
```

Comment: Now showing the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Buffer' of undefined

Comment: You didn't do something right. Can you add the code that you have changed in the question? It looks like you called property `.Buffer` with `.`.

Comment: app.post('/register',upload.single('img'), (req, res) => {
    var img = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
    var encode_img = img.toString('base64');
    var final_dp={
        contentType:req.file.mimetype,
        dp:Buffer.from(encode_img,'base64')
    }
    try {
    const password = req.body.fPass;
    const Spassword = req.body.sPass;
    if(password == Spassword){
        var obj = {
            dp: final_dp,

Comment: Still showing the same error:
' TypeError: Cannot read property 'Buffer' of undefined '

Comment: Can you try to `console.log(img)` and `console.log(req.file.path)` to see if that is maybe undefined?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236595/discussion-between-guntuku-chaitanya-and-nenad-milosavljevic).